# How do I wait until an asynchronous process inside a loop is finished before exiting the loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, asynchronous

I have some asynchronous code running inside a JavaScript `forEach` loop. I want to wait until the code inside the asynchronous process has finished running before proceeding after the loop.

Example below:

`ids` is an array of strings. `db` is a node module I created to work with MongoDB

```
var appIdsNotFound = "";
var count = 0;
ids.forEach(function(id) {
    output[count] = {};
    //console.log(id);
    db.findApp(id, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            fatalError = true;
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            if (result) {
                output[count] = result;
                //console.log(output[count]);
                count++;
            } else {
                appNotFound = true;
                appIdsNotFound += id + ", ";
                console.log(appIdsNotFound);
            }
        }
    });
});

//more code that we want to wait before executing
```

Is there a way to wait before executing the rest of the code that is outside the loop, and if so, how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Do you think about using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? Wrap your async function with promise, on error call reject and on success resolve, then collect all promise objects to array and do **Promise.all()**.

Comment: I have never used a promise. Every tutorial I've seen is different. Guess it's time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming `db` is some module to access your DB, try to look for the synchronous version. This assumes you are ok with synchronous, since you're attempting to write it that way, waiting for everything before proceeding.
2. If your db library uses promises, you can use it in conjunction with `Promise.all`. Fire a request for each item, collect all their promises in an array, feed them to `Promise.all`. The promise from `Promise.all` will resolve when all promises resolve.

   ```
   const promises = ids.map(id => db.promiseReturningFindApp(id));
   const allRequests = Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
     // responses is an array of all results
   });
   ```
3. If you don't have a promise-returning version of your API, wrap `db.findApp` in a promise, do suggestion #2.

   ```
   function promiseReturningFindApp(id){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       db.findApp(id, (error, result) => {
         if(error) reject(error);
         else resolve(result);
       });
     });
   }
   ```

Options 2 and 3 are asynchronous, and as such, you technically don't "wait". Therefore, code that needs to execute after can only reside in a callback.

Comment: `db` is an implementation of mongoose.js from npm. It contains my schemas and various functions for reading and writing the database. I've written everything in async to achieve the fastest times possible.

Comment: @JoelTrauger yes, mongodb already supports promises, so just use approach #2

Comment: I don't think MongooseJS fully supports promises though since it requires me to `require('mpromise');` for the promises to work properly. I'm not familiar with that npm package.

Answer (score 0):

You could make every item into an function and use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/):

```
var async = require('async');

var output = [], appsNotFound = [];
var appRequests = ids.map((id) => (cb) => {
    db.findApp(id, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            appsNotFound.push(id);
            return cb();
        }
        output.push(id);
        return cb();    
    })
})

async.parallel(appRequests, () => {
    console.log('N# of Apps found',output.length);
    console.log("Ids not found:",appIdsNotFound.join(','))
    console.log("N# Apps not found:",appIdsNotFound.length)
})
```

If the DB don't handle it, try to use `async.serial`.

You can make something similar with promises if you prefer, but this requires less lines of code.